# Detecting if an object is an instance of a superclass in typescript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, subclass, es6-class

If I have two classes like this in typescript (v4.2.3)

```
class A {
   hello: string;
}

class B extends A {
   bye: string;
}
```

Where B is a subclass of A, but later in my code I want to know if a given variable is an instance of class A. How can I do this, the following is false:

```
const b = new B();
b instanceof A; // this is false?
typeof b; // this is 'object'
```

Comment: There's something else going on in your code. With the lines you've given us, `b instanceof A` returns true. Note that `typeof b` should be `object`, as `typeof` always returns the primitive type or `object`, not the class name.

Comment: TypeScript isn't relevant to this question

Comment: Good call, something is going wrong in the packaging of my code and module resolution. Thanks!